# SQL stored procedure that needs to execute based on look up table value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL stored procedure that needs to execute only if lookup table value has today's date.

If not then it should run again after 30 minutes with the same criteria.

How can I do that?

Look up table has just one date row value = '12-14-2012'. It will be change by another process.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can do it for you. Note this code will not execute, you will need to replace items with your values.

```
DECLARE @Today DATE
SET @Today = GETDATE()

IF EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(ColumnName as DATE) = @Today)
    BEGIN
      EXEC Sproc Here
    END
```

Comment: Nice. However, my problem is, let say, this run once when it matches the conditio, how do I make sure the SP don't run again next time.

Comment: You could always put a flag in your table, indicating that it has executed. Then you can check for that flag. Such as a BIT field, like HasExecuted BIT NULL, and if set to 1, then you know it has been executed for that specific record.

Comment: Ok, great, after I run the job/sp successfully and change the bit to 1. What will happen tomorrow? Do I have make that bit to 0 for the fresh start?

Comment: That will have to be something that you decide. If you want some "historical" records to see if it ran for that day, perhaps you could insert new records into that table based on the date that it needs to be executed. Then you can run reports showing if something failed or not. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you can use SQL Server agent to schedule the proc. To decide whether or not to run you can put something like this in the proc

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM LOOKUP WHERE colname = convert(varchar, getdate(), 110))
BEGIN 
    --do stuff
END
```

Comment: Thank you. I know this will work. I have to schedule something to make sure this run once. So, here is how it will look like. At 8am this  job runs and the condition didn't match, so the sp didn't run. Now 9 am it find the matches and run. at 10 am it should not run because it already run successfully at 9am.

Comment: After a successful run, why not just delete the one row (or just clear the value) from your lookup table?